# Solving multi-call recursion with iteration

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

I have a program that generates tiles outwards of itself, in the (x+1, y), (x, y+1), (x-1,y) and (x, y-1) directions, and calls itself recursively to do so, as follows:

```
void tileGenerate(int x, int y){
     //generate a tile at (x, y)
     if (!tile[x + 1][y].generated) {
          tilegenerate(x + 1, y);
     }
     if (!tile[x][y + 1].generated) {
          tilegenerate(x, y + 1);
     }
     if (!tile[x - 1][y].generated) {
          tilegenerate(x - 1, y);
     }
     if (!tile[x][y - 1].generated) {
          tilegenerate(x, y - 1);
     }
```

Generating a tile, however takes a lot of memory and is causing segfaults due to stack overflow (right?). Is there a way to emulate this loop iteratively? I would like to preserve the outward generation nature instead of just using two for loops that go in the x and y directions, generating row by row.

Comment: It could cause a stack overflow from deep recursion, but more likely it seems that there isn't any bounds to this... it would just keep generating tiles in all directions, off the ends of your existing tile array (including using negative index values) and accessing portions of the array tile that don't exist would cause segfaults.

Comment: It's always possible, but as there isn't any tail recursion, you'll need to simulate a stack.  However, a more likely cause of the segfault is that you don't have any conditions to terminate the recursion at the edges of `tile`, which leads to accessing outside of the matrix.

Comment: In addition to the already mentioned concerns about watching the edges of the tile array, I also notice just now that there is omitted code at the comment where you actually do the work of generating a tile... which you say is memory expensive.   If the memory is not cleaned up  before the function exits, you would indeed be adding lots of memory with each recursion.   You might instead put the code to generate the tile contents in a separate function (that you call where the comment currently is) rather than inline with this code.   Either that or free up temp memory use sooner

Comment: There is limiting to the bounds of the array, the borders of the array are already generated and therefore the function will not call tilegenerate on a border. I will look into scoping the generation code into another function and see if that clears up the stack

Comment: @BrydonGibson That should work but you'd have to assure the starting point is not on a border, or the check for the item past the border would cause a segfault.

Comment: Yes, that is assured, it is placed well within the outer bounds